# jQuery bind text fields (hour estimates) to increment sum of values

Tags: jquery

I have a project where I have a job estimate form that has several "text" input fields that need to be totaled and the total reflected in the last field, which is a text field with id="estimateTotal", for example.

Is there an easy way to do this with jQuery?

I want the estimateTotal field to update each time a value is entered or changed in one of the estimate fields.

For example, I have this html:

```
<div class="field-group">
    <input class="text long-field" name="customfield_1" type="text" value="" placeholder="Hrs to prep">
    <input class="text long-field" name="customfield_2" type="text" value="" placeholder="Hrs to design">
    <input class="text long-field" name="customfield_3" type="text" value="" placeholder="Hrs to code">
    <input class="text long-field" name="estimateTotal" id="estimateTotal" type="text" value="" placeholder="Total Hrs">
</div>
```

And I need to have the values of all the text fields that are not the total hours field to be totaled into the "estimateTotal" field.

I'm sure there are probably a dozen ways to do this with jQuery, just looking for some suggested approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should suffice:

```
var totalField = $('#estimateTotal');

$('.field-group').children('input:not(:last)').on('keyup', function(e) {
    var total = 0;
    $(this).parent().children('input:not(:last)').each(function() {  
        total+= (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) ? 0 : parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    totalField.val(total);
});
```

Here's a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WFN9R/)

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
var sum=0;
$(".field-group input").on("keyup",function(e){
$(".field-group").find("input :not([id='estimateTotal'])").each({
         sum += parseInt($(this).text());
    });
});
$("#estimateTotal").val(sum);
```